# Synology remove admin account access to user folder

Tags: synology

Good evening,

At home we just started using a Synology NAS DS1815+. The problem is 3 of us have the admin password making it impossible for one of us having a trully private folder on the NAS.

My question is: Is it possible to create a folder where just a specific user has access to it and you can see its contents even if you have the synology NAS admin password?

cheers and thanks in advace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can open file browser in synology, and create new shared folder, which will be encrypted, and do not selet automatic connection after start...

but to have more admins is generaly not wise idea, and sooner or later some other trouble will come up...

i suggest you, you create admin user, and agree with others, not to use it - loggins are visible in logs...